# VectorDrawable is not displayed Correctly on Android

Tags: android, android-vectordrawable, svg-android

I have some icons in SVG format.
Converting it to VectorDrawables does not seem to be OK.
It is sharp as it should be

Does any one has an idea what could be the reason?

Here is the original SVG icon:
[image]

and here how it look like on Android as a VectorDrwable:
[image]

Comment: `Here is the original SVG icon:` Hopefully, you know that an SVG **is different** from a VectorDrawable (which only uses a **subset** of the SVG directives)

Comment: True,but when I checked the paths for both SVG and VectorDrawable it was the same exactly so I have no clue why it is drawn differently

Comment: You should **convert** the original SVG to an Android proprietary  VectorDrawable file. I'm sure that (at least) the headers are different.

Comment: Here is both of them : https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwTqAXuWb_bCYWh2Z0cyNndqdkU/view?usp=sharing
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwTqAXuWb_bCNUszUzFMSXJKRk0/view?usp=sharing Could please tell me what kind of headers should I change?

Comment: The first link is an **apk**, not an **svg** - how can I compare them?

Comment: SVG https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwTqAXuWb_bCdHY1R3k5aVJtRkk  Sorry about that

Comment: The only difference I'm able to spot out (at a rough glance) is that the fill color is different: SVG: `#acacac`, VectorDrawable: `#000000`.

Answer (score 1):

This question is quite old, and I hope you found a solution long ago, but this seems like svg behavior that I've experienced before. In my case, the issue was that the svg was using the wrong `fill-rule`.

The gist is that the svg spec includes two `fill-rule`s; `nonzero`, and `evenodd`. Android only supports `nonzero` prior to API level 24. You can change the fill rule directly in the `VectorDrawable`, but you might need to make some edits to your svg so the paths are looping in the right direction.

For anyone who encounters this later, check out [this article](https://medium.com/thoughts-overflow/the-mystery-of-the-disappearing-holes-a-gripping-tale-of-using-svg-in-android-442f6035a452) for a great explanation.